# After setting manually, computed property do not observe changes anymore

Tags: ember.js

here is jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wumufifasu/edit?html,js,output with input where it is possible to enter id of the item and its text will be displayed nearby.
But there are two items with same "id" property and thus to display correct text they  can be selected from the list on the bottom.

With "manual selection"  itemId is changed only once - very first time , afterwards it's not set and subsequently "itemText" CP which observes itemId is not triggered.

The weird thing is that this effect is caused by setting value for "itemText" CP, and doesn't occur when `this.setProperties({'itemId': item.id, 'itemText': item.text});` is replaced with `this.setProperties('itemId', item.id);`
Why's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property cannot be both a computed property and also one that you set. If you set what was a computed property, the value you set destroys the computed property definition. The property becomes a simple value. You have to decide: do you want Ember to compute the property, **or** do you want to set it yourself?

(Actually, there is a notion of setting a computed property. But it requires writing the computed property definition in a special way. You don't need that here. If you interested in this feature, see http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties).

The problem is, you are using duplicate IDs--not a good idea. When the user clicks on one of the items, you pass the item itself as the parameter to the action, but from the ID of the item, since there are duplicate IDs, in the controller action you no longer have any way to find the correct item from the ID. I would suggest adding an `index` parameter to the loop, then passing that back as the action parameter.

By the way, why are you defining `items` in your component? It duplicates the `items` used as the model. You should pass the model into the component.

See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/likazerune/1/edit?html,js,output.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the setting CP nuance. The jsbin represents simplified model of the application, in which there is no model, and is designed the other way around, but I will take that into account, for the next projects.

Answer (score 1):

For ember `2/3` You can preserve computation by usng `get` and `set` method directly:

```
     ...

     yourProperty: computed('propertyForComputation', {
         get(key) {
          // logic here
         },
         set(key, value) {
          // logic here
         },
     }), 

     ...
```